# :hover почему то не работает должным образом

Tags: hover

```css
li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
  padding: 7.5px 10px 7.5px 8px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 222px;
  display: block;
}

.text {
  width: 165px;
  height: 25px;
  text-align: left;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}

li a:hover text {
  color: white;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navigation-list">
  <li>
    <a href="/">
      <div class="image">
        <span class="icon-game"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="text">Играть</div>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Почему при наведении на  цвет текста не меняется?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Точку пропустили:

```css
li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
  padding: 7.5px 10px 7.5px 8px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 222px;
  display: block;
}

.text {
  width: 165px;
  height: 25px;
  text-align: left;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}

li a:hover .text {
  color: white;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

li:nth-child(3) {
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navigation-list">
  <li>
    <a href="/">
      <div class="image">
        <span class="icon-game"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="text">Играть</div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```